# A property of convex cones in Euclidean spaces

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity, convex-analysis

EDIT: Let $K$ be a closed convex cone in a Euclidean space of finite dimension. Assume it is non-zero and not the whole space.

> Does there exist a non-zero point $x\in K$ such that 
>   $$(x,y)\geq 0 \mbox{ for all } y\in K?$$

An equivalent reformulation of the problem: Given a convex compact subset $L\subset S^{n-1}$ of the unit Euclidean sphere. Does there exist a spherical ball of radius at most $\pi/2$ containing L?

Remark. In dimension 2 the answer is positive.

Comment: Don't you mean "$L\subseteq B^n$"?

Comment: Could $K$ be all of Euclidean space?

Comment: @BenMcKay Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Follows from the hyperplane separation theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem).